# Not able to delete all cookies of current domain in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, webdriver

I am working on Selenium webDriver in which I am using the method `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`
But this method is deleting all cookies from the current domain except one. Strange!!

I am using Chrome right now.

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible cause and what we can do to delete all cookies for the current domain?

Comment: It could be a subdomain cookie, it could be that a AJAX calls keeps happening in background and still adds a new cookie. It could difference between a secure and insecure cookie. Those are the points I can think of

Comment: Yes it is a cookie created by AJAX call but in a different domain. So what is the ideal way to delete this cookie?

Comment: You will have to browse the location of that domain and then only delete cookies will work. Delete cookies will only delete the cookies for current site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

This will only delete cookies on current domain. It won't delete cookies of any other domain.

So if you need to delete cookies of those domain then you need to first browse to a page from that domain and then call the `deleteAllCookies` method again

Answer (score 0):

I had to wait all ajax operations to finish then call `deleteAllCookies()`, then it worked.

```
public void ajaxWait(long seconds) {
    try{
        while(!waitForJSandJQueryToLoad()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seconds -= 1;
                if (seconds <= 0) {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException var4) {
                var4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // no jQuery present
                e.printStackTrace();
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    // wait for Javascript to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState")
                    .toString().equals("complete");
        }
    };

    return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}
```

Comment: This is complex, bu the idea to wait for everything to load is correct

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I wanted to log out of the system. I thought that I had deleted all cookies by calling:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

After the statement finished, however, the system navigated me to the home page.

The solution for me is to navigate to log in page then delete the cookies again:

```
driver.get(target_url);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```